# What is the probability of picking a point in the edge of a ball?

Tags: probability, geometry

How can we describe the probability law of a point in the edge of a ball?

First I thought about something like:

If $ r $ is the radius of the ball, then maybe I can try the volume formula:
$$ \int_0^r 4 \pi x^2 dx$$
But quickly find out it was a mistake because the volume of a surface is null.
$$ \int_r^r 4 \pi x^2 dx = 0$$

However, I can't make my mind if it was a smart or naive mistake.

A ball is continuously constituted of all its spheres, so "what is the probability to pick one sphere amongst all of them?"

Oh sh*t, did I just answer myself trying to calculate the probability of a discrete element in a continuous set? And it is... zero...

There is an infinity of points in the edge of a ball but the probability to pick one is zero? I intellectually don't like that  but anyway.

So let's try a new question: **What is the probability law of a point in an annulus ($\mathcal{A}$) in the edge of a ball ($\mathcal{B}$)?**

I can't proof it but I think the probability of a point being in the annulus is the ratio between the volume of the annulus ($\mathcal{V_A}$) and the volume of the ball ($\mathcal{V_B}$).

$$ \frac{\mathcal{V_A}}{\mathcal{V_B}} = \frac{\frac 43 \pi (r^3 - (r-\epsilon)^3)}{\frac 43 \pi r^3} = \frac{r^3 - (r-\epsilon)^3}{r^3} = \frac{1}{3r^3}\int_{r-\epsilon}^{r} x^2 dx $$

So is it possible the answer is:

$$
\mathbf{P}(\mathbf{X}\in \mathcal{A}) = \frac{1}{3r^3}\int_{r-\epsilon}^{r} x^2 dx
$$

Thank you and I hope you understand my english

Comment: Assume that the ball has radius $R$.  Assume that you select a point at random anywhere inside or on the ball.  For the moment, forget the Math, and just focus on intuition.  On the one hand, the probability of selecting a point greater than $~(R/2)~$ away from the ball's center is certainly greater than the probability of selecting a point less than $~(R/2)~$ from the ball's center.  This is because Volume is linear to the cube of the radius, rather than being linear to the radius itself.  ...see next comment

Comment: When you talk about the probability of something, you *must* first describe what the probability distribution is that you are using.  If we were to pick a random point from the surface of the ball and ask if it is from the surface of the ball... then the probability is trivially going to be $1$.  If we were going to flip a coin, and if heads pick the north pole of the ball on the surface, and if tails pick the center of the ball... then the probability is $\frac{1}{2}$, and so on...  Without context, this question is meaningless and unanswerable.

Comment: Assuming you pick a point from the ball uniformly at random, then as you say the surface has volume $0$ and so the probability is zero.  This is despite there being infinitely many points on the surface... that is completely irrelevant here.  There is no contradiction.

Comment: Re my last comment, however, despite this, the probability that the selected point will be exactly at radius $~= R,~$ **still** has to be $~0.~$ The fact that volume is linear to the cube of the radius is insufficient to overcome the fact that if you select any real number, at random, from the set $~[0,1],~$ the probability of selecting the number $~1~$ itself is **zero**.  Alternatively, you can reason that surface area is linear to the **square** of the radius, and come to the same conclusion.